# Handling multiple Bluetooth Pairing Request Dialogs at once

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, uialertcontroller

I have an app that integrates with BLE devices. I can connect to any number of devices. When initiating a pairing from the app to the device via `[CBCentralManager connectPeripheral:options:]` the system bluetooth pairing request alert will fire if no previous pairing information is found. This all works great.

However, I am implementing a functionality that discovers, pairs, and reads characteristics from multiple devices at once. This also works great if the devices have been paired previously. But if this is the first pairing for more than one of the devices, only one of the pairing request alert controllers is displayed. What makes this even more difficult is that I also don't receive a failed connection error from CB for the other devices waiting for response from the pairing dialog.

Is there any way I can elegantly handle situations where there are multiple pairing requests needing attention? It would be helpful if at least one of these was possible:

- The ability to complete the outstanding pair requests sequentially
- Notification of failed pairing for other devices
- Knowledge of whether a pairing request dialog will be fired *before* initializing the pairing so I can pair one at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no APIs in CoreBluetooth that lets you interact with the pairing.
Are you in control of the firmware of the peripherals you want to be able to pair with? If so, you can enable notifications and send events how the pairing process is going. That way you know in the app the current status of a pairing process.

For some examples, by looking at status and error codes (details depends on your peripheral BLE stack), you will be able to identify when iOS shows the pair dialog, when the user presses cancel and when pairing succeeds. It will also be possible to identify when iOS didn't put up the pair dialog.